# Error while connecting db

Tags: java, couchdb, couchdb-2.0

I am using CoucheDB2.0 and got below error message

> Text:CHARACTER:net.sf.json.JSONException: JSONObject["update_seq"] is not a number.

while below line was executed -

```
Database studentCouchDb = studentDbSession.getDatabase("mycompany");
```

I am using couchdb4j-0.1.2.jar along with other dependent jars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CouchDB 2.0, the [update_sequence was changed from a number to any valid JSON object](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/whatsnew/2.0.html#upgrade-notes).  It sounds like your CouchDB library doesn't understand this, and is still expecting a number.

I suggest updating to the latest CouchDB driver, or filing an issue with its author/vendor if necessary.

Comment: thanks for your reply... i tried this.. but did not get a latest jar which can solve the issue. so I downgraded the couchDB version and it works fine now with existing jar file.

Comment: If you found the answer helpful, you are encouraged to up-vote and accept it.